# How to make a function that outputs an array with a predefined size?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a function that outputs an array of predefined size. The function is dependent on variables `x`, `y`, `rx`, and `ry`, and `d`. Variables `x` and `y` are directly related to the cartesian values. `rx` and `ry` are the radius of the blobs generated from the function.

I have already converted array indiies from the traditional `0, 0` on the upper left corner to the middle most pixel. This array should always be odd in herms of length and width.

The blob below gives me one array at a time. I need a stack of arrays I can add together. When I change `x` and `y`, the size of the array changes, but I need the array to be the same size or zeroed out at on the borders.

I have some code that follows:

```
def equation(x, y):
    return 1 * np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))


def make_matrix(xs, ys, x_min=nxs, y_min=nys): #makes cartesian values
    out = [] #outputs array
    for i in range(x_min, xs - center_x):
        row = []
        for j in range(y_min, ys - center_y):
            row.append(equation(i, j))
        out.append(row)
    return out

blob = np.asarray(list(np.float_(make_matrix(x, y))))
```

Comment: Your prose does not match the code at all. I have provided an answer that matches your code, and hopefully shows you the tools that you need. I am unlikely to be able to match the prose portion without a lot of additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorization is your friend here. No need to compute lists element-by element when your function can be evaluated element-wise for an entire array.

```
def make_matrix(xs, ys, x_min=nxs, y_min=nys):
    x = np.arange(x_min, xs - center_x).reshape(1, -1)
    y = np.arange(y_min, ys - center_y).reshape(-1, 1)
    out = np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))
    return out
```

The [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) operations create a 1xN row vector for `x` and a Nx1 column vector for `y`. These shapes ensure that [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in the [`add` (`+`)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) operation expands `x**2 + y**2` to an array of the final size you want.